# Como verificar se uma constante existe na classe ou em um namespace?

Tags: php, classes, constantes

No PHP, para verificar se uma constante existe utilizamos a função `defined`. Como abaixo, para os dois casos de declaração da constante:

```
const MY_TEST_1 = 'my test 1';

define('MY_TEST_2', 'my test 2');

var_dump(defined('MY_TEST_1'), defined('MY_TEST_2')); // true, true
```

E quando eu declaro uma `constante` em um `namespace` ou em uma `classe`? Como faço para verificar a existềncia das mesmas?

```
namespace StackOverflow {

   const LANG = 'pt-br';

   class StackOverflow
   {
        const MY_CONSTANT = 'minha constante';
   }
}
```

Partindo do exemplo acima, como verificaria a existência de `StackOverflow\LANG` e `StackOverflow\StackOverlow::MY_CONSTANT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você irá usar a função [`defined()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.defined.php).

Em ambos os casos você precisa informar o *namespace* completo:

```
<?php

namespace StackOverflow {

   const LANG = 'pt-br';

   class StackOverflow
   {
        const MY_CONSTANT = 'minha constante';

        public static function hasConst($const)
        {
            return defined("static::$const");
        }

   }

}

namespace {

    if (defined('StackOverflow\LANG')) echo "Opa";

    if (defined('\StackOverflow\StackOverflow::MY_CONSTANT')) echo "Opa";

}
```

Comment: Se eu quiser verificar a constante que está fora de escopo de namespace, eu teria que fazer assim `defined('\MY_CONSTANT')`?

Comment: Isso. Se você tiver uma constante no namespace global (`\\`) e você precisa verificar ela dentro de um namespace você utiliza a barra.

Comment: Interessante! Funciona com `static` também!

Comment: a parte com `static` vi [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.defined.php#94953).

Comment: Como o `static` trabalha com a classe atual, então o cara definiu o `defined('static::CONST') dentro da classe abstrata. Muito útil :)

Answer (score 3):

você pode usar a função `defined` mas não esqueça de passar o nome da classe junto

```
<?php

namespace StackOverflow {

   const LANG = 'pt-br';

   class StackOverflow
   {
        const MY_CONSTANT = 'minha constante';
   }
}

namespace teste {
    var_dump(defined("LANG")); //false
    var_dump(defined("MY_CONSTANT")); //false
    var_dump(defined("StackOverflow\LANG")); //true
    var_dump(defined("StackOverflow\StackOverflow::MY_CONSTANT")); //true
}
```